# How can I define the ":" range operator for my own compound type in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, range

I have the following type definition:

```
type TransitionMatrix
  A :: SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}
  d :: Array{Float64,1}
  I :: Array{Int64}
end
```

and would like to allow for the following: if we have T :: TransitionMatrix, I'd like the range functionality (IE, P[:, 1], P[:, 3], etc.) to work at it would for T.A. How can I do this? I have done similar things to define the "size" of a transition matrix as below, but I don't know how to allow the colon operator to function how i'd like. Thank you!

```
function Base.size(T :: TransitionMatrix, dim)
  return size(T.A, dim)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to write versions of `getindex` and `size` for your `TransitionMatrix`. For example:

```
import Base: getindex, size
getindex(A::TransitionMatrix, indx1, indx2) = @show (indx1, indx2)
size(A::TransitionMatrix) = size(A.A)
size(A::TransitionMatrix, d::Integer) = size(A.A,d)
```

Then

```
julia> A[:,2:3]
(indx1,indx2) = (1:5,2:3)
(1:5,2:3)
```

The parser expands `:` into `1:size(A,d)`.